# The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it

Tags: system.reactive

I'm creating an observable and I'm creating the subscription separately:

```
class CustomQuery {
    string Name;
    IObservable<int> Occurrences;
}

public IEnumerable<CustomQuery> GatherCustomQueryObservables()
{
    yield return new CustomQuery() {
        Name = "NameXXX",
        Occurrences = Observable.Create<int>(
            observer => 
            {
                int occurrences = this.webservice.GetOccurrences()
                observer.OnNext(occurrences);
                return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
            }
    );
}
```

By other hand, there's another method deals with these `CustomQueries`:

```
public void CommitCustomQueryObservables(IEnumerable<CustomQuery> queries)
{
    foreach (CustomQuery query in queries)
    {
        query.Occurrences
            .Select(o => o)
            .SubscribeOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .ObserveOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.DispatcherScheduler.Current)
            .Subscribe(
                occurrences =>
                {
                    string strOccurrences = occurrences > 0 ? occurrences.ToString() : "";
                    this.Label.Text = strOccurrences;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception:

> The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it.

The last line of the stacktrace is at

```
System.Reactive.Concurrency.DispatcherScheduler.get_Current(‌​).
```

I don't quite figure out how to handle it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running this code in a Console or WinForms app? The DispatcherScheduler can only be used with WPF applications. Furthermore, if you're intending to unit test this code, it's usually a good idea to inject the schedulers your intend to use rather than use the static ones shown above.

Comment: Yes, I'm running this code in a WinForms app. Isn't there any way to get this goal? I've just installed `System.Reactive.Winforms.Forms` nuget reference, nevertheless, it's getting me the same exception.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Forms you need to use the [ControlScheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Windows.Forms/Reactive/Concurrency/ControlScheduler.cs) for synchronization, not the DispatcherScheduler.

Now you've added the `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` package this can be achieved by simply using `[observable].ObserveOn([control])`; in your example this could be:

```
public void CommitCustomQueryObservables(IEnumerable<CustomQuery> queries)
{
    foreach (CustomQuery query in queries)
    {
        query.Occurrences
            .Select(o => o)
            .SubscribeOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .ObserveOn(this.Label)
            .Subscribe(
                occurrences =>
                {
                    string strOccurrences = occurrences > 0 ? occurrences.ToString() : "";
                    this.Label.Text = strOccurrences;
                }
            );
    }
}
```